Convert iff expression in informatica to snowflake query
I am trying to convert the below IFF expression from INFORMATICA to Snowflake SQL statement(the column code is a column from a table), but I am unable to:
iif(substr(CODE,0,6)='CE-PUU', 
    '70NPU'||substr(CODE,7),
    iif(substr(CODE,0,5)='AR-70', 
        '70N'||substr(CODE,6),
        iif(substr(CODE,0,3)='HD-', 
            '70D'||substr(CODE,4), 
            decode(substr(CODE,0,4),'HP-B','7PB','HP-A','70P','HP-C','7PC','HP-X','7PX','IT-T','70T','HP-D','7PD','HP-Z','7PZ',substr(CODE,0,4))||substr(CODE,5) 
        )
    )
)


i tried to use case statement but its throwing NULL

Hi - please format your code so that it is readable (e.g. indent each IIF statement) and add the CASE statement you managed to write to your question, also formatted as code

Snowflake has IFF instead of IIF
so you could use it like it is:
iff(substr(CODE,0,6)='CE-PUU', 
    '70NPU'||substr(CODE,7),
    iff(substr(CODE,0,5)='AR-70', 
        '70N'||substr(CODE,6),
        iff(substr(CODE,0,3)='HD-', 
            '70D'||substr(CODE,4), 
            decode(substr(CODE,0,4),
                'HP-B','7PB',
                'HP-A','70P',
                'HP-C','7PC',
                'HP-X','7PX',
                'IT-T','70T',
                'HP-D','7PD',
                'HP-Z','7PZ',
                substr(CODE,0,4))||substr(CODE,5) 
        )
    )
)


Try this
CASE 
    WHEN SUBSTR(CODE, 1, 6) = 'CE-PUU' THEN '70NPU' || SUBSTR(CODE, 7)
    WHEN SUBSTR(CODE, 1, 5) = 'AR-70' THEN '70N' || SUBSTR(CODE, 6)
    WHEN SUBSTR(CODE, 1, 3) = 'HD-' THEN '70D' || SUBSTR(CODE, 4)
    ELSE 
        DECODE(SUBSTR(CODE, 1, 4), 
            'HP-B', '7PB', 
            'HP-A', '70P', 
            'HP-C', '7PC', 
            'HP-X', '7PX', 
            'IT-T', '70T', 
            'HP-D', '7PD', 
            'HP-Z', '7PZ', 
            SUBSTR(CODE, 1, 4)
        ) || SUBSTR(CODE, 5)
END

